# typescript return type is being widened to whole enum

Tags: typescript

In the code below if I don't specify kind in each action with the 'as' keyword the inferred type for method widens it to any of the Kind types. Is there a way to avoid repeating 'Kind.PAYPAL as Kind.PAYPAL'?

```
enum Kind {
    CASH = 'CASH',
    PAYPAL = 'PAYPAL',
    CREDIT = 'CREDIT'
}

const Cash = () => ({
    kind: Kind.CASH as Kind.CASH,
});

const PayPal = (email: string) => ({
    kind: Kind.PAYPAL as Kind.PAYPAL,
    email
});

const CreditCard = (payload: { cardNumber: string, cvv: string }) => ({
    kind: Kind.CREDIT as Kind.CREDIT,
    payload
});

type PaymentMethod = ReturnType<
    typeof Cash
    | typeof PayPal
    | typeof CreditCard
>;

function describePaymentMethod(method: PaymentMethod): string {
  switch (method.kind) {
    case Kind.CASH:
      // Here, method has type Cash
      return "Cash";

    case Kind.PAYPAL:
      // Here, method has type PayPal
      return `PayPal (${method.email})`;

    case Kind.CREDIT:
      // Here, method has type CreditCard
      return `Credit card (${method.payload.cardNumber})`;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're at TS3.4+ you can use [`const` assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions) as in `kind: Kind.CASH as const`

Comment: @jcalz - that's an acceptable answer, make it one and I will accept it if you care for some karma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using TypeScript 3.4 or higher, you can use [`const` assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions) as in

```
const Cash = () => ({
  kind: Kind.CASH as const
});

const PayPal = (email: string) => ({
  kind: Kind.PAYPAL as const,
  email
});

const CreditCard = (payload: { cardNumber: string; cvv: string }) => ({
  kind: Kind.CREDIT as const,
  payload
});
```

to have the type of the `kind` property interpreted as narrowly as possible:

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYOwrgtgBA0gliAJlA3gKClAwgQQMoASUAvFAES6FkA0GUACjgJqMAyJ5jLOrNdWAJQCiAEQCSAFQ4Vh4iWTQBfNGgDGAexABnAC7YAhloAWHABQBKEgD4op9JgDWCRAC5YzgHSUihqBu06SuYA3Cr+ugz6AJ70+gA2ZsAQ+nBxbroATggA5pbENnZ0Tkhu8EgeXGxQvuE6tJhJKXFBoWqaEVgZwIhwOlj6GcikpgAO0XHq+q6ofgOIAHKQAEbAGek6WSDZwX4Abrvrm9lQinkF9lDF02WIXrKS1Vp+7XV0Y1ETUy0qOlEjwJEohBQDoALLAHRGdRDKACCFgDIgCR-YAAHjov3+6gAZgZjFAAD5QTHAHGA2IJIkksmdbq9fqDNBWVrYsAgVQ6OCaKCIYBaVRZFaxIEg8GQ6GmYHi6bC4EgMEQqGIcyHHKoOhaADuvVUJkliuhHiulgumFUhgBNy8+AILjomEwAHpHVACKtgNQoFKlVAjL4SXijPaHV0dAiQOR+sYyK0HbMtJbPJUeHa406XW6up7vdDff6UeT4sHMKHw1AAAbCim2AAkKBzt0aqVO5djDvNCfc5UEokkqbTztd7uzBuQfqeAdpPT6c2LUFLiIrU96s0Gtfro4870+t3Ng0WEBWGRboUwymUQA)

Prior to TS3.4, or in cases where you don't want to use a `const` assertion, you have to rely on TypeScript's [heuristics for determining when and when not to widen literals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676), such as the following helper function:

```
const lit = <T extends string | number | boolean | void | null | {}>(x: T) => x;
```

which returns `x` as a string/numeric/boolean literal if possible, since the type `T` is constrained by a union including `string`, `number`, and `boolean`.  And then you'd use it like this:

```
const Cash = () => ({
  kind: lit(Kind.CASH)
});

const PayPal = (email: string) => ({
  kind: lit(Kind.PAYPAL),
  email
});

const CreditCard = (payload: { cardNumber: string; cvv: string }) => ({
  kind: lit(Kind.CREDIT),
  payload
});
```

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYOwrgtgBA0gliAJlA3gKClAwgQQMoASUAvFAES6FkA0GUACjgJqMAyJ5jLOrNdWAJQCiAEQCSAFQ4Vh4iWTQBfNGgDGAexABnAC5QANnD2kAPFOAAPHaERaougE4IA5lAA+UcBABGwB+6hvdXV9YABDEACAN3U4ZA9wfX0AlEUAPgAKCwAuKAkAShI0qAsAbhUNbT0sMK0ACw4MwuJijPRMAGsERFzDHQz4JAA6SgJ8pXzytU1dBjCAT3ow5NIM4AgwuH1cxxdm1vaoLqReowHuoa42fNpMdc39CanK2awHYEQjGodkVYAHBb6dRhHqoKCqMI-ABykF8Dh2OicIGcpXBUSiCKRrkU+ygbTox1BfXOw0EokkNzoAPmQJBTxUOnmf2Ac3mEFAOgAssAdHV1L8oAIeWAHCAJEzgCY6IzmeoAGbYWoNDwy4Dy1lLZIqiXqt4fL6QxBoNJTOVgECqHRwTRQRDALSqJy+JZsjnc3n8jLsj2gl3skBcnl8xD5TEuVB0LQAdyMqgaXqD-KGhMKh0wEK0LMGiBG+AI2TomEwAHpi1ACH5gNQoN7g1A6rUoKrFfVC0X3joRZEKEqyFMi+DalmLlceAWByWyxX3tXa-z643my7NW3MB2u1AAAbL5Z4gAkKDnOfuWxxm-7RYzw9Jskk44npfLldnieQDbszb1nx03yNE6g66iluX5GIOPz7oer5DNStI5hC0Kwn4Z7lJgyjKEAA)

Either way should work for you.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!